# FortiGate & FortiAuthenticator - Mapping users to Groups for VPN using Radius

Tags: fortigate, radius, fortinet

I need help from you guys since I can't find anything wrong with my setup and it still doesn't work:

I authenticate my Fortigate SSLVPN users against FortiAuthenticator. I want to map some users to a Firewall group in my FG using Radius attributes. I used the "Fortinet-Group-Name" and "fortinet-Access-profile" attributes (set to "test")

this is my Fortigate config : (FAC-Group for users without attributes, grp-test for users with attribute set to "test")

```
config user group
    edit "SSO_Guest_Users"
    next
    edit "FAC-Group"
        set member "FortiAuthenticator"
    next
    edit "grp-test"
        set member "FortiAuthenticator"
        config match
            edit 1
                set server-name "FortiAuthenticator"
                set group-name "test"
            next
        end
    next
end
```

this is my debug output :

```
[1309] __fnbamd_rad_send-Sent radius req to server 'FortiAuthenticator': fd=16, IP=--------------(------------:1812) code=1 id=100 len=101
 user="domain\user" using PAP
[1179] send_radius_challenge_rsp-Timer of rad 'FortiAuthenticator' is added
[1348] fnbamd_auth_handle_radius_result-Timer of rad 'FortiAuthenticator' is deleted
[1767] fnbamd_radius_auth_validate_pkt-RADIUS resp code 2
[319] extract_success_vsas-FORTINET attr, type 1, val test
[353] extract_success_vsas-FORTINET attr, type 6, val test
[1374] fnbamd_auth_handle_radius_result-->Result for radius svr 'FortiAuthenticator' ---------- is 0
[1304] fnbamd_radius_group_match-Skipping group matching
[1018] find_matched_usr_grps-Skipped group matching
[217] fnbamd_comm_send_result-Sending result 0 (nid 0) for req 1251334245, len=2014
[747] destroy_auth_session-delete session 1251334245
authenticate 'domain\user' against 'pap' succeeded, server=primary assigned_rad_session_id=1251334245 assigned_admin_profile=test s
ession_timeout=0 secs idle_timeout=0 secs!
Group membership(s) - test
```

As you can see, the FortiGate matches and extracts the Group Name but still skips the user mapping to the new Group. I tried deleting the "FAC-Group" but then I was unable to even connect.

FG : 6.4.2
FAC : 6.1.2

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this. [Here's a link](https://pio.nz/2021/02/13/fortigate-sslvpn-with-azure-mfa/) to the page that explained it to me. (Scroll down to "Gotcha 1: Set the Group".)

Relevant excerpt:

> If you set the group to anything other than Any, things won’t work. This may seem a bit odd, as for example you might wish to limit VPN access to an AD group called ‘VPN Users’. It would make sense right? But this group would actually be a check against a Vendor specific AV pair that the radius server may return and not related to AD at all. See this link: https://kb.fortinet.com/kb/documentLink.do?externalID=FD40923
>
> [...] Result 0 means the authentication worked, but you then see that the group matching is skipped. This is because the NPS server did not return the AV Pair Fortinet-Group-Name which is what gets used for matching. More details here: https://kb.fortinet.com/kb/documentLink.do?externalID=FD36464
>
> So basically you need to control the access some other way. Either by Individually allowing Dial-In access. (AD User Manager –> Find User -> Properties -> Dial-In) or by Creating an NPS Policy to allow access to your AD group

I did find a Fortinet article describing how to set up Windows NPS as a RADIUS server with this group. I'm not going to paste the whole article here, but [here is a link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210827005947/https://inside.fortinet.com/doku.php?id=sslvpn_with_radius_using_active_directory_and_nps) to an archive.org-saved version.

Hope that helps!